# Dereferencing an unsigned char pointer and storing its values into a string

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, casting

So I am working on a tool that dereferences the values of some addresses, it is in both C and C++, and although I am not familiar with C++ I figured out I can maybe take advantage of the string type offered by C++.

What I have is this:

```
unsigned char contents_address = 0; 
unsigned char * address = (unsigned char *) add.addr;
int i;

for(i = 0; i < bytesize; i++){     //bytesize can be anything from 1 to whatever
  if(add.num == 3){
    contents_address = *(address + i); 
    //printf("%02x ", contents_address);
  }
}
```

As you can see what I am trying to do is dereference the unsigned char pointer. What I want to do is have a string variable and concatenate all of the dereferenced values into it and by the end instead of having to go through a for case for getting each one of the elements (by having an array of characters or by just going through the pointers) to have a string variable with everything inside.

NOTE: I need to do this because the string variable is going to a MySQL database and it would be a pain to insert an array into a table...

Comment: Are you actually just trying to hexify a byte buffer?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I am trying to hexify a byte buffer, I have the size and the address of what I want to hexify.

Comment: *It is both C and C++*... it is *either* C or C++. They are different languages, and while C++ is almost a superset of C, it is not a strict superset. Not all C programs are valid C++ programs, and few C++ programs are valid C programs.

Comment: The posted code will (not) work equally in C and C++ ... the differences aren't applicable here, so it is both C and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this that I borrowed from this link:

http://www.corsix.org/content/algorithmic-stdstring-creation

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string hexifyChar(int c)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << c;
  return ss.str();
}

std::string hexify(const char* base, size_t len)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    ss << hexifyChar(base[i]);
  return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand what you want to do here (why do you assign a dereferenced value to a variable called ..._address)?.

But maybe what you're looking for is a stringstream.

Comment: The question is just basically how to concatenate unsigned chars dereferenced values into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively efficient version that performs only one allocation and no additional function calls:

```
#include <string>

std::string hexify(unsigned char buf, unsigned int len)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(2 * len);

    static char const alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != len)
    {
        result.push_back(alphabet[buf[i] / 16]);
        result.push_back(alphabet[buf[i] % 16]);
    {

    return result;
}
```

This should be rather more efficient than using iostreams. You can also modify this trivially to write into a given output buffer, if you prefer a C version which leaves allocation to the consumer.